# Record mouse movements for Animation = gone?

Tags: animation, camera, keyframes

What happened with that?

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Mstram/IPO_Mouse_Recording
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Aligorith/Record_Tool

I am trying to record camera framing with the mouse (the camera already has keyframed positions - basically I try to be the camera operator, pushed on a dolly)

Any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 7):

- Set Automatic Keyframe insertion
  [image]
- Play animation (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>)
- Move the camera

**NOTE:** Since the animation plays in a loop, pay attention not to replace the keyframes you've just added...
[image]

Comment: I tried that actually. I keyframed my cam X,Y,Z movement, then with the record button activated, I play the animation, orient the cam with Shift-F to try and frame the shot. but it refuses to work well, it gets extremely jerky because Shift-F doesn't expect the camera to move, somehow???

Comment: I've added a demo. Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for a lot taking the time to do this. unfortunately what I need to do is to record only the camera's orientation, while the camera moves along a path that I created earlier. if you try to do exactly what you did, but recording only the rotation (selecting the rotation active keying set), you'll see that Shift-F acts very erratically, it's quite unusable. Do you confirm that or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think recording mouse movement has been thought to achieve "erratical" effect (sometimes I use it to animate puppets). Maybe is not the tool you need. You can achieve your goal easier adding rotation keyframe manually. BTW "Record mouse movements for Animation" is not gone ;)

Comment: hi! is this gone? http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Mstram/IPO_Mouse_Recording   to record an animation for an object's hue with the mouse, for example... (following a music, for example, or something very "human", and realtime, that would take a long time animating with manually-placed keyframes...)

Comment: Yes, it is. To animate only few channels, you can lock the others. After you've drawn a curve, you can scale it vertically to increase the effect or copy the keyframes to another channel.

Comment: OH, we use "fly look" to animate the camera? I tested, that works, the hotkey in 2.8 is `shift` + `\``